# How do I make a plotly express area chart animation using wide dataframe format?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, animation, plotly-python

I was poking around `plotly.express` charts and animations and I encountered a problem that I dont know how to deal with. If someone could help I'd be very thankful. So here's how my dataframe looks (it actually has additional index, but it doesn't really matter because it's not used):

```
YearWeekISO ALL      Age18_24 Age25_49
2020-W52    0        0        0
2020-W53    10       0        6
2021-W01    50       0        26
2021-W02    1400     190      720
2021-W03    96722    2158     44434
2021-W04    406326   15738    186148
2021-W05    913702   56894    420448
2021-W06    1312204  75910    559022
2021-W07    1883038  92950    652650
2021-W08    2390826  104078   699688
2021-W09    2873676  110784   732604
2021-W10    3215104  114296   752118
2021-W11    3565462  116494   767442
2021-W12    3974814  118154   781284
2021-W13    4130168  119008   787832
2021-W14    4159884  119270   789706
```

What I have so far is a static plot that looks like this:

[area chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQ7sa.png)

Code that generated the image above:

```
fig = px.area(
    df, 
    x='YearWeekISO', 
    y=['ALL', 'Age18_24', 'Age25_49'],
    # animation_frame='YearWeekISO',
)
fig.show()
```

As you can see, the `animation_frame` parameter is commented. What I want to happen with the animation is that it should just go from left to right, according to the `x` values (`YearWeekISO`), like in line chart race. How can I achieve that? I want to also add, that I tried to do this with long dataframe format after using `df.melt()`. The code would then look like this:

```py
fig = px.area(
    df, 
    x=df.index, 
    y='value',
    color='TargetGroup',
    # animation_frame=df.index,
)
fig.show()
```

This code would produce the same exact results and have the same exact flaw. So how do I go about this? Am I choosing wrong `animation_frame` value or do I need to change up my dataframe in order for this to work? I also tried to change the date format but it didn't seem to work either, or maybe I did something wrong. And by the way, it seems that, in this case, `animation_frame` doesn't accept dates in actual datetime format, only strings or ints. For the code I followed these tutorials:
https://plotly.com/python/animations/ 
https://plotly.com/python/wide-form/

Comment: It seems to me that you are looking for a animation that just show the evolution week after week at each step. Am I wrong?

Comment: Yes, simple as that. Although It would be cool if it was smooth, not just 16 frames jumping from one to another.

Comment: as plotly works frame by frame I don't think you'll have much luck unless you try to replicate the code in [raceplotly](https://github.com/lc5415/raceplotly). Maybe the easiest way to achieve it is using [flourish](https://flourish.studio/examples/)